# I can't customize the pause button in Android Kotlin. Can maybe some help me?

Tags: android, kotlin

**Hello everyone, Im still super noob in Android and kotlin and cant customize the pause button which will stop the sound in my application, so my pauseButton just dont want to work. mb someone can help me? Im using MediaPlayer and audioManager and my sound(alarm sound) is in res/raw**

````
lateinit var bindingClass : ActivityMainBinding
lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     bindingClass = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)
        val audioManager: AudioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

        bindingClass.imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raw)
            mediaPlayer.start()
            val myIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MyAlarmService::class.java)
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this@MainActivity, 0, myIntent, 0)
            val alarmManager: AlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3)
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Starting Service Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        bindingClass.pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raw)
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying)
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            val alarmManager: AlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Service Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        bindingClass.soundButton.setOnClickListener {

            val maxVolume = audioManager.mediaMaxVolume
            val randomIndex = Random().nextInt(((maxVolume - 0) + 1) + 0)
            audioManager.setMediaVolume(randomIndex)
            toast("Max: $maxVolume / Current: ${audioManager.mediaCurrentVolume}")
        }
    }
    fun playSound(view: View) {}
    fun pauseSound(view: View) {}
}
fun AudioManager.setMediaVolume(volumeIndex:Int) {
    this.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            volumeIndex,
            AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI
    )
}
val AudioManager.mediaMaxVolume:Int
    get() = this.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

val AudioManager.mediaCurrentVolume:Int
    get() = this.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}```
````

Comment: Keep a reference to your media player in a class level property. You are creating a new MediaPlayer in your pause button code, which has no relation to any other MediaPlyer you have created.

Comment: Big thanks, now its work!)